# function to style part of a string

Tags: jquery, string, styling

Can anyone advise on this? I'm trying to create a jquery function that will take the last 3 characters of a string and style them differently. In my case half the font-size.

So in a string like €100.50 the .50 would be smaller

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Or maybe if a plugin/script already exists let me know

Thanks!

Dec

Comment: It really helps when you're asking for a "function" that you specify in the tags what language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you want modified needs to be wrapped in another html element to which you can add a class or inline style to make css adjustmets

Assuming this staring html, and using jQuery to get and set the mosified text/html:

```
<span>€100.50</span>
```

.

```
$('span').html(function(idx, oldHtml) {
    var startStr = oldHtml.substring(0, oldHtml.length - 3)
    var endStr = '<small>' + oldHtml.substring(oldHtml.length - 3) + '</small>'
    return startStr + endStr;

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vJ63t/

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please point me in the right direction? ...

Using `replace` wrap the text in a tag and add a class to style it with CSS:

```
$el.html( $el.text().replace(/.{3}$/, '<span class="small">$&</span>') );
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/epuzag/4/edit

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for! In fact everybody that contributed was bang on the money, so thank you everybody for your time and effort! What an amazing community!

Comment: @decbrad - than why wont you approve his answer? His answer is better, efficient, smarter and the right way.

Comment: How can I mark 2 solutions as being correct? Many roads lead to Rome after all!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use a function that get the length of the wanted string and cuts the last 3 letters of it, then put them in a new string into a new tag (span or something) with a wanted class

Answer (score 0):

well, does not necessarely involve jquery .
you could take the string as a parameters wrap into a styled DIV.

something like:

```
 txt = $("#id").text();
 txt = style_string(txt);

 function style_string(string){
      ...
     if(){
        string = "<div class='class-to-style'>" +string+"</div>"
      }....

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function formatString( txt ) {

    var i = txt.lastIndexOf( "." ); 
    if( i === -1 ) return txt; // if txt => $10 return

    return txt.slice( 0, i ) + "<span class='smaller'>" + txt.slice( i ) + "</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use a formatter like:

HTML

```
<div id="price"></div>
```

CSS

```
.decimal {
 font-size:10px; 
 color:black;
}
```

JS

```
function formatPrice(price, containerId, digits) {

  var startStr,
      endStr,
      containerElem = $("#"+containerId);

  //cut last specified digits
  startStr = price.substr( 0, price.length - digits );
  endStr = price.substr( price.length - digits, price.length );

  //DOM elements

  $("<span/>")
    .text(endStr)
    .addClass("decimal")
    .appendTo(containerElem)
    .parent()
    .prepend(startStr);
}

var price = "€100.50";
formatPrice(price, "price", 3);
```